# File contains corrupted data EPPlus

Tags: excel, xlsx, epplus

I am trying to create a new excel sheet(xlsx) from existing excel sheet(xlsx) using EPPlus.

My existing excel sheet contains 4 worksheets and I want to update some cells in new excel sheet and save in new location.

Here is my code

```
public string RunSample22(DirectoryInfo outputDir)
{
    FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo(@"F:\bin\Debug\ReportTemplateFile.xlsx");

    // Making a new file 'Sample2.xlsx'
    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"E:\Test" + @"\Sample22.xlsx");

    if (newFile.Exists)
    {
        newFile.Delete();
        newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\Sample22.xls");
    }

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile, tempFile ))   // getting error in this line
    {
        // Openning first Worksheet of the template file i.e. 'Sample1.xlsx'
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test";

        // Save our new workbook
        package.Save();
    }
    return newFile.FullName;
}
```

And Getting below error in my catch block.

"File contains corrupted data."

What I am missing or any suggestions.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Does the original Excel file contain data that is explicitly not supported by EPPlus? I also had some issues with corrupted data in EPPlus (at least in version 3.x). Which version of EPPlus are you using ... maybe you should try the 4.x (currently in beta)?